# NullPointerException in a list based implementation of a simple message board

Tags: java, list, null-pointer

I'm trying to create a list structure for a simple message board usinsg lists of topics, which are themselves lists of messages, with my own implementation of binodes. However I'm getting a null pointer exception when I'm trying to add a post to my topic.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at TopicList.remove(TopicList.java:110)
    at TopicList.addPost(TopicList.java:80)
    at TestHarness.main(TestHarness.java:13)
```

My code is as follows:
TestHarness.main

```
TopicList list = new TopicList();
list.addTop(new Message("user1", "post1"), "Topic 0");
list.addTop(new Message("user2", "post2"), "Topic 1");
list.addPost(new Message("user3", "post3"), 0);
System.out.println(list);


TopicList.addPost()

public void addPost(Message m, int id){
    Topic t;
    t = (Topic) getTopicNode(id).head();
    this.remove(getTopicNode(id)); //This is line 80 in my code
    t.addMessage(m);
    topiclist = new Node(t, topiclist);
    }


TopicList.remove()

private void remove(Node n){
    if (n.tail().equals(null)){ // this is line 110
        n.prev().nullTail();    
    }  
    else{
        n.prev().join(n.tail());
    }
}
```

Thanks for helping.

Comment: have you not answered your own question?
`n.tail()` I am guess is `null`.

Comment: Hi. This is unfortunately not enough information for helping you. There are two possible references that might be null. Either "n" is null or "n.tail()" results in null. If n is null, then the caller of remove(n) passes in null. Line 80 shows that remove is called with "getTopicNode(id)", which might be null. So you must debug your code to find the problem. [If n.tail() is null, then you possibly have problems in other portions of your code: The structure or the setup of youe list nodes might be wrong.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if `n.tail()` is `null`, the following line will throw NPE:

```
if (n.tail().equals(null)){
```

You need to check:

```
if (n.tail() == null){
```

instead.

Comment: Yep, `n.tail().equals(null)` is not the right way to do it -- that will inevitably throw a NullPointerException before `equals` gets a chance to be true.  You need to compare directly to `null` as shown in the second line.